# How to add Horizontal Page Breaks to an Excel Worksheet using Interop. Excel?

Tags: c#, excel, winforms, excel-interop, page-break

So I am trying to add horizontal page breaks after every 11 rows of my Excel worksheet created and populated using Interop. Excel but have been so far unsuccessful in doing so. Here is my code snippet:

```
ws.HPageBreaks.Add(ws.Range["A11","D11"]);//ws=wb. Worksheets[1]
```

but it isn't working. Any advice is appreciated.

**Update:**
So after debugging and digging in the issue at hand, and using `ExcelApp.Visible = true;` , I have come to a very weird conclusion. The Horizontal Page Breaks are indeed being added at the intended locations in the worksheet using `ws.HPageBreaks.Add(ws.Range)` but upon saving and reopening the worksheet,the pagebreaks donot appear!

Answer (score 1):

I think D11 has no effect there. You might add the breaks in a loop. ie:

```
for (int i = 12; i < ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count; i+=11)
{
    ws.HPageBreaks.Add(ws.Range["A"+i]);
}
```

PS: Parameter is "Before", therefore it is before 12.

EDIT: A full sample code:

```
void Main()
{

    // A Sample for getting a DataTable to Excel
    // Note: Normally I would use CopyFromRecordset or QueryTables
    // this is just a sample using a DataTable and array

    // ornek datatable
    // Sample DataTable
    var tbl = new System.Data.DataTable();
    new SqlDataAdapter(@"
      WITH  tally ( SiraNo, UniqueId, RandNumber, RandDateTime )
            AS (
                SELECT TOP 500
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY t1.object_id ), 
                        NEWID(),
                        CAST(CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS VARBINARY(4)) AS INT) AS DECIMAL) / 1000,
                        Cast(DateAdd(second,-CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS VARBINARY(4)) AS INT), getdate()) as datetime)
                FROM   master.sys.all_columns t1
                CROSS JOIN master.sys.all_columns t2
                )
      select SiraNo, UniqueId, RandNumber, 
        RandDateTime, RandDateTime as DateCol, RandDateTime as TimeCol
      from tally;",
        @"server=.;Database=master;Trusted_Connection=yes;")
        .Fill(tbl);

    object[,] arr = new object[tbl.Rows.Count + 1, tbl.Columns.Count];
    for (int i = 0; i < tbl.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        arr[0, i] = tbl.Columns[i].Caption;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < tbl.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < tbl.Columns.Count; j++)
        {
            arr[i + 1, j] = tbl.Rows[i][j].ToString();
        }
    }

    // Excel dosya yarat ve arrayi koy
    // Create Excel workbook and paste from array
    Excel.Application xl = new Excel.Application();
    var workbook = xl.Workbooks.Add();
    xl.Visible = true;

    Worksheet ws = ((Worksheet)workbook.ActiveSheet);
    Range target = (Range)ws.Range[(Range)ws.Cells[1, 1], (Range)ws.Cells[arr.GetUpperBound(0) + 1, arr.GetUpperBound(1) + 1]];
    target.Value = arr;
    ((Range)ws.Range["D:D"]).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm;@";
    ((Range)ws.Range["E:E"]).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy;@";
    ((Range)ws.Range["F:F"]).NumberFormat = "hh:mm;@";
    
    
    // Add Horizontal page break after every 11 rows

    for (int i = 12; i < ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count; i += 11)
    {
        ws.HPageBreaks.Add(ws.Range["A" + i]);
    }

}
```

This is the partial result:

[image: Partial excel output]

EDIT2: This is just to show the code is working:

```
void Main()
{

    // A Sample for getting a DataTable to Excel
    // Note: Normally I would use CopyFromRecordset or QueryTables
    // this is just a sample using a DataTable and array

    // ornek datatable
    // Sample DataTable
    var tbl = new System.Data.DataTable();
    new SqlDataAdapter(@"
      WITH  tally ( SiraNo, UniqueId, RandNumber, RandDateTime )
            AS (
                SELECT TOP 500
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY t1.object_id ), 
                        NEWID(),
                        CAST(CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS VARBINARY(4)) AS INT) AS DECIMAL) / 1000,
                        Cast(DateAdd(second,-CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS VARBINARY(4)) AS INT), getdate()) as datetime)
                FROM   master.sys.all_columns t1
                CROSS JOIN master.sys.all_columns t2
                )
      select SiraNo, UniqueId, RandNumber, 
        RandDateTime, RandDateTime as DateCol, RandDateTime as TimeCol
      from tally;",
        @"server=.;Database=master;Trusted_Connection=yes;")
        .Fill(tbl);

    object[,] arr = new object[tbl.Rows.Count + 1, tbl.Columns.Count];
    for (int i = 0; i < tbl.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        arr[0, i] = tbl.Columns[i].Caption;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < tbl.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < tbl.Columns.Count; j++)
        {
            arr[i + 1, j] = tbl.Rows[i][j].ToString();
        }
    }

    // Excel dosya yarat ve arrayi koy
    // Create Excel workbook and paste from array
    Excel.Application xl = new Excel.Application();
    var workbook = xl.Workbooks.Add();
    xl.Visible = true;

    Worksheet ws = ((Worksheet)workbook.ActiveSheet);
    Range target = (Range)ws.Range[(Range)ws.Cells[1, 1], (Range)ws.Cells[arr.GetUpperBound(0) + 1, arr.GetUpperBound(1) + 1]];
    target.Value = arr;
    ((Range)ws.Range["D:D"]).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm;@";
    ((Range)ws.Range["E:E"]).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy;@";
    ((Range)ws.Range["F:F"]).NumberFormat = "hh:mm;@";


    // Add Horizontal page break after every 11 rows

    for (int i = 12; i < ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count; i += 11)
    {
        ws.HPageBreaks.Add(ws.Range["A" + i]);
    }
    xl.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs(@"d:\temp\IWasWrong.xlsx");
    xl.Quit();
}
```

Print preview **after opening the saved file**

[image: Print preview after opening the saved file]

Comment: I have tried your method but it didn't work.

Comment: @Candy, well it works. "it didn't work" is the best of replies I get :) What does that mean? What is the error message? What happens? With the method I gave you get a page break "before" row 12, 23, 44 and so on. I thought that was what you needed.

Comment: @Candy, edited to add a full working sample.

Comment: @Candy. I am afraid you were wrong. I added just 2 lines of code at the bottom of the original code and edited my reply to show the saved xlsx in print preview mode. Probably it would take another 2-3 weeks for you to reply but anyway there it is.

Comment: Isn't there any method to open the saved worksheet in Print preview by default?

Comment: xl.ActiveWindow.View = XlWindowView.xlPageBreakPreview;

Next time you can look into Excel documentation.